# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am executing one process, which is called one stored procedure from my application. The expectation was, the application will call procedure and once the procedure execution is completed, then the control will be returned back to the application and will return execution status from the application. The application will wait until the procedure executing is getting completed.

But I am getting below error exactly after 1 hour of job starts. The Procedure will take around

*Exception in thread InputTask9 in time Wed Aug 19 12:27:56 MST 2020 is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
Error code in thread InputTask9 in time Wed Aug 19 12:27:56 MST 2020 is 17002
Error message in thread InputTask9 in time Wed Aug 19 12:27:56 MST 2020 is IO Error: Connection reset
Error Cause in thread InputTask9 in time Wed Aug 19 12:27:56 MST 2020 is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset*

I am using unix app server and oracle database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to show your code, please.

Comment: Sounds like a network/firewall/SQL*Net timeout issue rather than a code problem. You'll need to investigate which.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Sorry, I don't have access the application code.

Comment: @Alex Poole : Thanks for your comment., the "SQL*Net timeout" parameter configured in unix server side or db side?

Comment: On the database server, but at operating system level, not within the database. It's more likely to be firewall though, or the user profile within the DB (idle_timeout), or even within your application's connection pool settings. The error would make me look at network/firewall first.

Comment: @Alex Poole- Thanks a lot, really appreciated. There can be chances in the application server (operating system level). Anyway I will check with network/firewall team. Also I have checked Idle time out, which is set as zero(means infinity).